# Can't install bcrypt with npm

Tags: python, node.js, windows, hash, bcrypt

I want to install bcrypt to crypt password for a backend API with Node.js, on Windows 10.

Errors during install : https://sharemycode.fr/r52

I have the package in node_modules but when i use it, it seems it's not execute.
I tried lot of solutions, but nothing seems to work. Python 2.7 is installed, Windows Build Tools too.

Thank you if you try to help me !

Comment: What are your node and npm versions?

Comment: node 12.3.1 - npm 6.13.2

Answer (score 0):

delete your node_modules folder and then run `npm i`
sometimes the node_modules do a little cache managment due to which they are unable to install with correct version
if you are using linux try 
`npm i --unsafe-perm`